Adafruit_fingerprint from the adafruit circuit python library
This is my code with the error, I'm using a raspberry pi model 4B running off of thonny
import serial

import adafruit_fingerprint

#uart = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=57600, timeout=1)

uart = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=57600, timeout=1)

#uart = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=57600, timeout=1)

finger = adafruit_fingerprint.Adafruit_Fingerprint(uart)

error:
finger = adafruit_fingerprint.Adafruit_Fingerprint(uart)
AttributeError: module 'adafruit_fingerprint' has no attribute 'Adafruit_Fingerprint'

Why does it give me an attribute error when I know that attribute is in the adafruit fingerprint library, its even in the example from the library.

please format your code ... put ``` on a blank line before the code and also on a blank line after the code

did you look at the example code carefully?
